# Learning new thing and implementing new thing in a company

Tags: learning, php, development-process, access

In my new company, I wanted to use Doctrine DBAL for data abstraction. But it's not working due to the PHP Version 5.2 we are using on our development server.

Here it's all about rights issues. You don't have access to anything.

I can't use anything new due to this rigidity of the product!

What can I do about this? How should I talk to my TL and project manager about this?

Comment: Don't forget that upgrading from PHP 5.2 to 5.3 can have (big) consequences on existing applications that were written before 5.3 existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IN general identify the problem you are solving by choosing a new technology. Tell your team lead about the problem and how your solution solves it.

- When talking to management you should present the business case

  - now we spend this much time on coding with errors and when we use Doctrine DBAL we will spent approximately this much time without errors
- When talking to fellow developers just show how cool it is and how much it reduces tedious code.
- When talking to DBA's show them query speeds, and and database load.
- When talking to the security expert show them that there is less room for creating security holes

Create a proof of concept to back up your claims.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to have them walk into a demonstration, show them why and what is not working and suggest them the alternatives.

Once everything is clear with a practical demo, I hope they will understand what is the problem and veto on the solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

I would second with kamaal. A proof-of-concept is what people find a good way to evaluate a new technology. Please create a PoC and put it for evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do some homework/get your facts straight and quantify a few things (or at least gather enough information to put things into perspective.).

1. Determine how much effort it is going to take to upgrade you app/site. Obviously the easier this is the better.
2. How much does it take to handle data in your current method. No sense in claiming an improvement if you don't know where you're starting, so have a baseline.
3. What improvements can you expect to get out of the new technology? Of course you have many reasons for doing this, so make everyone else aware of them.
4. What are the short-term setback as a result of making the switch and can your company afford to do this? Are you in the middle of a new upgrade and have a major deadline to meet?

KeesDijk has some great points about knowing your audience.